# Usage of Win2d CanvasDrawingSession.Blend

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

In my project i would like to do a special kind of plot in Win2D. For this i need a procedure to overwrite geometries in the bitmap with new geometries, without losing the complete information of the previous geometries. The CanvasBlend.Min function seems to be the way to go.

I tried the following code, but the min function does not work as expected. It does not compare the geometry of the bitmap with the new geometry.

```
using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = offscreen.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            Rect myRect2 = new Rect();
            myRect2.X = 0;
            myRect2.Y = 0;
            myRect2.Width = 400;
            myRect2.Height = 500;

            ds.FillRectangle(myRect2, Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 255, 255));

            ds.Blend = CanvasBlend.Min;

            Rect myRect1 = new Rect();
            myRect1.X = 0;
            myRect1.Y = 0;
            myRect1.Width = 500;
            myRect1.Height = 200;
            //this color should overwrite the color before, because it is the minimum
            ds.FillRectangle(myRect1, Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(50, 255, 255, 255));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the **Remarks** of the [document](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasBlend.htm), you need to set the `ClearColor` property as `White` and set the `Opacity` property as “0.5” or “1” in your `CanvasControl`(if your `offscreen` is from a `CanvasControl`) to view the effect of `CanvasBlend.Min`. The default color is `Transparent` in `CanvasControl`.

Note that `Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(150, 255, 255, 255)` and `Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(50, 255, 255, 255)` are all white colors, you need to change them to other colors such as `Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0)` and `Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255)`. The first parameter of `Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb()` represent opacity.

Comment: Thank you i thought with the numbers in the wrong direction. My problem is, i do have a black background. Is there a possibility to invert the CanvasBlend.Min function?

Comment: Could you please tell me what “invert the CanvasBlend.Min function” means?

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I would need a function which takes the difference of the source and destination pixel. (So the oposite of the Add function).